# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'firstname' and 'lastname'

Tags: python

```
class Person(): 
   def __init__(self, firstname, lastname): 
        self.firstname = firstname 
        self.lastname = lastname 
   def fullname(self): 
       print("His full name is", self.firstname, self.lastname)

class Employee(Person): 
   def __init__(self, firstname, lastname): 
       super(Employee, self).__init__() 
       self.firstname = firstname 
       self.lastname = lastname 
   def fullname(self): 
       print("The name of this employee is", self.firstname, self.lastname)
```

Why if I write `emp1 = Employee(firstname="David", lastname="Labrecque")`, I got the error 
`TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'firstname' and 'lastname'` ?

Even if the two classes has firstname and lastname, I didn't have to overwrite it inside the "super(...).**init**" function.

**UPDATE**

Why if I run `emp1.fullname()`, `fullname()` from `Person()` class is never called? Only `fullname()` from `Employee()` class is called? Is there a way to call both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass params to to init function. Also no need to setup firstname, lastname in Empoyee

```
class Person():
   def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
   def fullname(self):
       print("His full name is", self.firstname, self.lastname)

class Employee(Person):
   def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
       super(Employee, self).__init__(firstname, lastname)

emp1 = Employee(firstname="David", lastname="Labrecque")
```

Comment: With my code, can you tell why if I run `emp1.fullname()`, `fullname()` from `Person()` class is never called? Only `fullname()` from `Employee()` class is called? Is there a way to call both of them?

Answer (score 1):

The parent class's `__init__` requires those two arguments.  You failed to supply them.  This is the rule for any function: you failed to provide a required positional argument.  Instead, just pass them along, just as the tutorials show you:

```
super(Employee, self).__init__(firstname, lastname)
```

Comment: Can you tell why if I run `emp1.fullname()`, `fullname()` from `Person()` class is never called? Only `fullname()` from `Employee()` class is called? Is there a way to call both of them?

Comment: Employee does not define its own fullname method, so it inherits the one on Person.  There are not two functions; there is only one.

Comment: Yeah, but when I call `emp1.fullname`, I got `The name of this employee is David Labrecque`, not `His full name is David Labrecque`. So `Employee.fullname()` has been called

Comment: I am sure, this question is somehow and somewhere a duplicate? Why did you not mark it as such?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate, too, but I couldn't find it any more than you.